# how to Disable All controls on the Silverlight Page

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I using silverlight in my siverlight page I want to disable all the controls.

I want to disable the entire page instead disabling the individual control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the `IsEnabled` property to false of the parent control should disable child controls.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.isenabled(v=vs.95).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Here goes the Answer..

```
<ContentControl x:Name="GroupOfControls" >
 <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
 'Design your own controls
 </Grid>
 </ContentControl>
```

Insert your Grid in the content control then
you can enable or disable all the controls on the silverlight page

```
GroupOfControls.IsEnabled = False

GroupOfControls.IsEnabled = True
```